# "this question is temporarily locked; please try submitting your answer again"

Tags: support, answers

I just got the following error:

> **Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:**
>
> - **this question is temporarily locked; please try submitting your answer again**

What in the world does that mean? How can a question be temporarily locked?

**EDIT**:
When and why does this happen?

How can I avoid it?

Comment: Any particular question here?

Comment: This is particularly annoying because it triggered a CAPTCHA when I next submitted the answer.

Comment: It sounds like a database lock; I'm not an expert on the internals, but I've seen pages get stalled before I compose an answer, so it's plausible that the system takes a temporary lock on the database record just before the page gets stalled. The Captcha occurs because the page never finished completely rendering, and the system thinks you are POSTing in close proximity to a completed page request.

Comment: I see SLaks has been **errorbanned!** Muahahahaha!

Comment: @EatmoreTwisters: I'd like to get answer, if you know one, please post it :p

Comment: Is this really an issue though? I assume this is something that happened only one time, correct?